# Why in Visual C# .NET in WinForm, tabPage1 will not update control content changes unless tabPage1 is selected?

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol, tabpage

So in a basic WinForm in Visual C# .NET I have tabControl1 with two pages: tabPage1 and tabPage2.

Let's say i have label1 in tabPage1, and a timer which updates every 10 seconds and changes the label1 to the current time:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.PerformClick();
}
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     label1.Text = "Last updated: " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "(local time)";
}
```

Now, if I have tabPage1 selected, the label1.Text updates just fine, even if i have the application minimized. However, if tabPage2 is selected, then label1.Text never updates until I select the tabPage1 which contains the label1.

Since in my application I have multiple tabs, which need to update content from the internet and populate labels and listviews, I need it to be able to update content on the tabs without me selecting.

How would I go about doing this, without programmatically forcing the user to select the tab to update content, which would disturb the user if they were using a different tab?

Note: I am trying to avoid this cludgy solution (which does work, but is very annoying to the user):

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int x = tabControl1.SelectedIndex;
    if (tabControl1.SelectedIndex != 0)
    {
        tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        label1.Text = "Last updated: " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "(local time)";
        tabControl1.SelectedIndex = x;
    }
}
```

Edit: I have tried tabPage1.Update(); and it does not work, still does not update the time so when I select tabPage1 after it should have updated a couple times, it shows the same time as before.

Edit2: I left out information critical to the problem. in timer1 I was doing: button1.PerformClick(); However, PerformClick(); will not work if the button is hidden. So when I'm in tabPage2 it is not properly clicking the button because the button is hidden in tabPage1. So the solution is to take the button code, put it into a method, and instead use the timer to do the method rather than PerformClick(), then all works fine no matter you are in tabPage1 or not.

Answer (score 0):

Along with the code that makes the changes, try calling `tabPage1.Update()`. Maybe it is not updating because it isn't visible. Either way, when the user changes to the tab to see its content it will probably call the method above and display its content updated. So it's not really necessary to update it if it is in the background.
I cannot test it myself as I no longer have visual studio :(

Comment: This is a strange behaviour. Can you check that the timer is still running when the tab is not selected? You could try adding a test button on another page and have it change the label text. Then check if the `label.text` property changed. Also, when you change back to tabPage1, is the label showing the correct value?

Comment: Hi Matheus I have discovered my problem and it was because I have omitted some code (trying to simplify), basically I was calling the label1.Text change from a button1.PerformClick(); and so the PerformClick() only works when the button is not hidden. When in tabPage2 ,the button is not showing, so performClick() does not work. Instead I created a separate method for the code, and then do the method in the Timer rather htan performclick(); in the timer. THanks for your attention and time though friend :)

Comment: Aaah I knew about that problem with `button.PerformClick()`, I had trouble with it long ago. If only I knew you were using it I could have told you. It is a good practice to avoid it. It also doesn't work if the button is disabled. Also, you're welcome, I'm sorry I couldn't help you, but I'm glad you found a solution :)

Comment: Also, please make an answer to your own question with your solution and mark it as the accepted answer so that others can find this information :)

Comment: One more thing (sorry). From the method `timer1_tick` you can call `button1_Click(sender, e);` it will have the exact same effect as `button.PerformClick()` except that it will work regardless of the button's visibility state. It will even work if you remove the button from the interface. This way you don't have to have another method polluting the code. Keep in mind when a project grows it can become pretty complicated to find a specific part of the code if it is not well organised, so you have to worry about this since the beginning :)

Answer (score 0):

See the edit in the question, the reason it wasn't working was because i used button.PerformClick() not a normal method call.